# What is borrow in and borrow out?

Tags: binary, binary-data, subtraction

When doing binary subtraction what is the borrow in and borrow out.
[image]

Comment: I tried...but nothing is there. I am trying to understand the above truth table but not sure where the borrow in and borrow out come in. I know it is something extremely simple but its not clicking for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary subtraction works just like decimal subtraction.  Subtraction is done column by column, from right to left.  For each column, you need to know two things:

1. Did the previous column need to do a borrow? (*borrow in*)
2. Did this column's subtraction need to do a borrow? (*borrow out*)

So if we are doing decimal subtraction:

```
  110
  -98
  ---
```

For the first column, there is no previous column, so no borrow in.  But there is a borrow out - we needed to borrow because `0 < 8`.  The result is `2`.

For the second column, there is a borrow in from the first column, and a borrow out since `0 < 9`.  The result is `1`.

For the third column there is a borrow in, but no borrow out (`0 >= 0`).